# dotnet core: Better way to get Environment from cli and add Json based on its value

Tags: c#, .net-core

I want to read `environment` from command line args and use its value to build Configuration itself. Environment could be passed by different ways (`--environment Staging`, `-e=Staging` etc.) so I do not want to parse `args` myself. I found that we can first build config to read only environment and than build whole configuration:

```
var envName = new ConfigurationBuilder()
    .AddEnvironmentVariables()
    .AddCommandLine(args)
    .Build()
    .GetValue<string>("Environment");

var contentRoot = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory();

var configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder()
    .SetBasePath(contentRoot)
    .AddJsonFile($"Configuration/appsettings.json", optional: false, reloadOnChange: true)
    .AddJsonFile($"Configuration/appsettings.{envName}.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true)
    .AddEnvironmentVariables()
    .AddCommandLine(args)
    .Build();
```

Is there better way to do this?

Comment: I believe that there was a bug in 2.0 that should be fixed in 2.1 that uses command line args before loading the default jsons so you can specify the environment via command line when using the default web host builder